# How to compare records and update one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image]

It is a little bit tricky for me so I need your help :)

I want to update the column `Relevant` to 0 `WHERE Contract_Status_Code` is 10 OR the `Date_Contract_start` YEAR is the same AND the `Ranking_Value` is lower than the other one ON all records that have the same `VIN`.

So I want to compare all records which have the same `VIN`.

Few examples to illustrate it:

1. I have there two records with the `VIN = 123456`. One of them (`ID = 6847`) has a higher `Ranking_Value (7)` than the other one (3). The `YEAR` is the same as well so I want to update the column relevant to 0 where the ID is `8105`.
2. Two records with the `VIN = 654321`. Both of them have the same `Ranking_Value` but the record with the `id = 11012` has the value 10 for the column `Contract_Status_Code` so I want to update the relevant column to 0 where the `ID = 11012`.
3. The last two records... They have the `VIN = 171819`. The first one (`ID = 11578`) has the higher `Ranking_Value`. But they have a different year where the contract has started. So I don't want to update both.

It is also possible that there are three or four records with the same VIN.

I hope you understand my problem. I'm from Germany so sorry for my English :)

Comment: What should happen, when you have 5 VIN rows with the same year and different ranking (e.g. 5,4,3,2,1)? All except 5 should be set to 0?

Comment: Right. Only the highest Ranking_Value should be have the value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering your ID column as unique or Identity column, I can suggest you the below query for your solution:

```
With cte
As 
(Select a.Id, a.VIN From Table a
Join (Select max(Ranking_Value) ranks,VIN From Table Group By VIN, Year(Date_Contract_start)) b 
on a.VIN=b.VIN And a.Ranking_Value = b.ranks)

update table
    set Relevant = 0 
where (Contract_Status_Code = 10) Or
ID Not In (Select id from cte)
```

Comment: `RANK` is t-sql reserved word, I would rather not use it as a column name. It works OK on the provided sample data but when there are more rows with the same year and various ranking then all the rows with less than maximum ranking will be set to 0.

Comment: @VDohnal I agree with you RANK is a reserved word, it was my mistake and I edited my code also. For the second point, when there are more rows with the same year and various ranking then all the rows with less than maximum ranking will be set to 0. and I hope you got your answer for it from @@Denis1893.

Comment: Yes indeed, so I gave +1.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you a +1 because of my few reputation points. But your code ist working very well. Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    update table1
    set Relevant = 0
    where Contract_Status_Code = 10
    or (VIN,Year,Ranking_value) not in(
        select VIN,Year,max(Ranking_Value)
        from table1
        group by VIN,Year
    )
```

Comment: Are you executing your code in SQL server 2020? because for me this type of code is not working in sql server 2012, 2008...!,     (VIN,Year,Ranking_value) not in(
        select VIN,Year,max(Ranking_Value)
        from table1
        group by VIN,Year
    )